# Расстояние между ячейками

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить расстояние между ячейками таблицы в UITableView. В интернете нашел только методы для добавления расстояния между секциями

Answer (score 3):

Я делаю проще, просто контент ячейки меньше на 5 поинтов с низу чем размер ячейки.